# How to join multiple dataframe objects into a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two objects I'm calling from a pandas dataframe `dataframe.columns` and `dataframes.dtypes`.

I'm trying to programmatically create a string that includes all the column names and data types in such a way that column 1 is next to data type 1, and so forth in the string.

The output should look like

`column1 varchar, column2 float, column3 int, column4 text`

Here's what I have so far:

```
col_str = ' varchar, '.join(dataframe.columns) + ' varchar'
```

which gives me a string output of

`column1 varchar, column2 varchar, column3 varchar, column4 varchar`

How do I incorporate `dataframe.dtypes` so that the columns correspond to the right data types?

I tried using a 2nd .join() but it didn't give the output I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
", ".join("{} {}".format(n, d) for (n, d) in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes))
```